# ERROR_APP_NOT_AUTHORIZED Firebase Phonenumber authentication in Ionic App

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

Iam getting an error

`unknown error verifying number Error instance: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException Error code: ERROR_APP_NOT_AUTHORIZED`

While trying to send otp in my ionic app using firebase .

```
this.firebase.verifyPhoneNumber(this.mobileNumber, 60)
  .then((creds) => {
    console.log(creds);
    this.verificationId=creds.verificationId;
  },(err)=>{
    console.log(err);
  })
```

Didn't find anything mentioning about this particular error , I did followed all steps correct as far as I know .I followed the below steps

1. got my sha1 string using my keystore
2. created project in firebase console and added app
3. added `google-services.json` in my root folder and copied config script need for web app in my main module.
4. installed `@ionic-native/firebase` and `firebase`

Can't get to know the reason behind this error , this error came when checked in my mobile using `cordova run android` .
**Thanks**

#### Update

---

I checked the same with  `angularfire2` and its working as expected .

1. In my module

`import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';`
and in imports

```
imports:[
  AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
  AngularFireAuthModule
]
```

2. In my component

`import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';`

//constructor

```
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  onOtpSend() {
    this.afAuth.auth
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(this.mobileNumber, new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier
        (
        're-container', {
          "size": 'invisible'
        }))
      .then((creds) => {
        console.log(creds);
        this.verificationId = creds.verificationId;
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

added `<div id='re-container'></div>` also in my component html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular error was due to,  checking with unsigned debug apk.

After signing it worked as expected..

Comment: did u use the debug.keystore to sign you app?